# how do i tell imacros to go to a url if the extracted TXT does not include a certain word?

Tags: javascript, url, eval, imacros, goto

i want to ask how do i tell imacros to go to a certain page if the extracted word is found. so far i came up with

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"module-select" EXTRACT=TXT

SET ref EVAL("var t = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.includes("and") window.location.href = ("https://www.google.com); return;")
```

but something is wrong in my JS script inside `EVAL` and i can't figure it out. i would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me sort this out. thanks in advance. What I was trying to accomplish is when the extracted text includes the word "and" it would go to google.com (just an example url) and if not, it would do nothing or skip to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the window object and unescaped double quotes in the `EVAL` command. So, try something like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"module-select" EXTRACT=TXT
SET ref EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}'.includes('and')) ? 'https://www.google.com' : 'javascript: undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{ref}}
```

Comment: thank you again shugar, you are really helpful regarding fixing imacros codes. i will try it once i get a hold of my laptop and update you with the result.